# Debug USB drive commands

Tags: android, adb

I have a car android system, that tries to read some unknown files once USB flash drive is inserted. If I put some proper files (only names without content) to USB stick car android system will automatically start engineering mode I'm looking for. I don't have ADB or ODB access to car, only USB port.

Can I somehow debug which files android system tries to read using USB port?

Comment: If you only can connect an USB stick, then I see only one way: use a device (e.g. a raspberry pi) that is connected via USB and that emulates an USB storage device. On the raspberry side you should be able to record the files accessed by the car Android system.